# Show that a continuous weakly harmonic function is harmonic.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, greens-function, greens-theorem

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n\geq2$. An
integrable function $u$ is said to be weakly harmonic in $\Omega$ if for all
$\varphi\in C_{c}^{2}\left(  \Omega\right)  $,
$$
\int_{\Omega}u\Delta\varphi=0.
$$
Show that a continuous weakly harmonic function is harmonic. (Remark: The
continuous assumption makes the proof easier but is not needed.)

Let's first assume $u\in\mathscr{C}^{2}(\bar{U}).$  Then integration by parts (or Green's identity) shows
\begin{align*}
0
&=\int\limits_{U}u\Delta\phi\;dx\\
&=\int\limits_{\partial U}u\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\nu}\;dS-\int\limits_{U}\nabla u\cdot\nabla\phi\;dx\\
&=-\int\limits_{\partial U}\phi\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}\;dS+\int\limits_{U}\phi\Delta u\;dx\\
&=\int\limits_{U}\phi\Delta u\;dx.
\end{align*}

I am unsure about this line that $$\int\limits_{\partial U}u\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\nu}\;dS-\int\limits_{U}\nabla u\cdot\nabla\phi\;dx\\
=-\int\limits_{\partial U}\phi\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}\;dS+\int\limits_{U}\phi\Delta u\;dx.$$ How do I get this and also after that why do we have $\int\limits_{\partial U}\phi\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}\;dS=0$?